# no conexion error 12505

Tags: oracle

Buen día, por favor ¿alguien me podría ayudar?

No he podido conectarme a la base de datos, he buscado en la web diferentes soluciones pero no logro arreglarlo. Adjunto la imagen del error y una validación en SQL*Plus, espero que me puedan ayudar

[image: conexion]
[image: validacion de conexion]
[image: validacion de servicios]

El contenido del archivo `TNSNames.ora` es el siguiente:

`C:\app\walte\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`

```
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Creo que el error es claro. ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo `TNSNames.ora`?

Comment: gracias por ayudarme pero no he podido aun  no se si me puedas guiar soy nuevo utilizando estos servicios aunque ya me he documentado no he podido dar con el problema a un soy bastante novato :(

Comment: Estoy tratando, por eso te pido que incluyas el contenido de tu archivo `TNSNames.ora` en tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc) (PRESENTATION = RO) ) )

ORCL = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) ) )

Comment: Por favor, utiliza el link que dice [**editar**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/387674/edit) al final de la publicación, e integra esta información al cuerpo de la pregunta. Utiliza formato de código para que conserve la indentación que tiene en el archivo original.

Answer (score 2):

Tu sistema no logra conectarse porque, según se ve en la imagen, estás poniendo un [Oracle SID](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID) (`xe`) que, tal como indica el error, no es reconocido, y no es reconocido porque no existe en tu archivo `TNSNames.ora`.

El SID es el Oracle System ID, y es único para cada base de datos dentro del entorno.

Asumiendo que solo tienes una instancia de Oracle instalada y corriendo, que estás ejecutando esta conexión en la misma máquina donde está instalado el servidor de base de datos y que es la instalación la que ha generado el archivo que publicas, el **SID** que debes utilizar para conectarte es **`ORCL`**.

```
SQL>connect scott/tiger@orcl;
```

Si tienes varias instancias de oracle, debes configurar el archivo [`TNSNames.ora`](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) de tal manera que puedas identificar cada una de las instancias de acuerdo a su SID y ubicación en la red.

Si es un equipo cliente, debe tener un archivo `TNSNames.ora` que describa las diferentes instancias a las que puede tener acceso en la red, con sus direcciones, protocolos e identificadores.